# Need to send two buttons backwards and forwards

Tags: c#, winforms, button, visibility

I've got the code, and all seems correct, I've had it reviewed and it seems impossible to find out why the button isn't doing what its coded to do. I'm making a Music player, and when I press the play button, it will be sent to the back and the pause button will become visible, when I next click the pause button, nothing happens and its primary function stops working all together. Here is the code for people to examine.

```
private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (_mp3Player != null)
            _mp3Player.Play();

        btnPlay.SendToBack();
        btnPause.BringToFront();
    }
    catch (Win32Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void btnPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_mp3Player != null)
        _mp3Player.Stop();

    btnPause.SendToBack();
    btnPlay.BringToFront();
}
```

Comment: Probably too obvious - but have checked that the Pause button OnClick is wired up to the `btnPause_Click(...)`?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Are buttons wired up? If answer is yes then try to set Visibility to true or false instead of using SendToBack() and BringToFront().

Comment: @Jonny Worked a treat, thank you :) keep forgetting to check if my events are wired up

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it would be best to use visibility?

```
  private void btnPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        if (_mp3Player != null)
        {
            _mp3Player.Stop();
        }
        btnPause.Visible = False;
        btnPlay.Visible = True;
  }
```

Or even the enabled property?

> ... btnPause.Enabled = false; ...

However I feel you could make it better by having it be the same button, with a value, so just have a value on it of true if it's player or false if it's pause and then in the click event check against that value to determine what it is currently and then just execute the relevant functionality and change the text or image that you have on the button.

Comment: Thank you! The visibility didn't seem to work and both of the buttons became invisible, but I would like to try having two functionalities in the button and used methods before that didn't work, but this sounds very safe so will give it a try :)

Comment: Be sure to keep me posted - if you need help just ask, and if it's the answer don't forget to mark it :D